# How to solve the wrong categories for xAxis in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, foreach, yii2

I have a problem in making categories for xAxis.
This is the example of my problem:

[image]

I have marked the problem on the picture above. Why "2" come from chart B? Chart A seems working fine, but chart B doesnt.

I have table like this:

**faculty**

[image]

**department**

[image]

**major**

[image]

For your information, the blue bar for lessthan25 and the black bar for between25to29.

I have controller like this :

https://pastebin.com/K6p1p7AN

I have index like this:

https://pastebin.com/27NVTcTH

I inspect the element, and the result for javascript is like this:

https://pastebin.com/UcN0FXAG

What may I do to fix that problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The "A" categories work properly because you have defined three categories, and you have three data points.

The "B" categories do not work properly, because you have three data points, but have only defined two categories.

[image]

Highcharts fills in the missing value with the next category array index - in this case, "2". You need to make sure you have as many categories as data points.